# Cannot install WSL2 Ubuntu on Windows

Tags: windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Installing, this may take a few minutes...
WslRegisterDistribution failed with error: 0xffffffff
Error: 0xffffffff (null)
Press any key to continue...

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-manual

I followed all the steps and I am using Build 19041.1. Is there a way to make it work without upgrading Windows?

Comment: Did you turn on both Hyper-V and WSL in Windows Features?   Control Panel, Programs and Features, Windows Features.

Comment: Also you should update Windows from 19041 to 19044 for WSL2

Answer (score 1):

There was a process using port 53, I checked this using the process manager, I also did netstat -a -o -n to get the PID of the application, and then I shut down the process and it worked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).